# The random variable X has homogeneous distrigution

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem with exercise:

The random variable X has a homogeneous distribution in the interval [0,1]. Random variable
Y = max(X, 1/2). Please find the expected value of a random variable Y.
I need to do this for discrete variables and also for continuous variable

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried using integral for continuous variable, but dont know how to start

Comment: That sounds about right. Try to convince yourself that what you're basically after amounts to computing $\int_0^1 \max(x,1/2)\,dx$.

Comment: I did it, but dont understand why it gives me integral from 0 to 1/2 of 1/2*dt + integral from 1/2 to 1 of t*dt

Comment: And what about the continuous variable, I know i have to sum the values but don't know what to put into this equation

Comment: $1.$ If  $0<x\leq \frac12$ then $\max \left(x,\frac12\right)=\frac12$ // $2.$ If  $\frac12<x<1$ then $\max \left(x,\frac12\right)=x$ So you make a case decision.

Comment: Ok i got it now, but still dont know how to start with continous variable

Comment: In general the expected value for a contin**u**ous random variable $X$ is $\mathbb E(X)=\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} x\cdot f(x) \,dx$ In your case the limits are $0$ and $1$. And this interval is splitted due case decision.

Comment: But here you have a continuous random variable.

Comment: Sorry I mean for discrete value, we already did for continuous, I don't understand how could we use the sum

Comment: I can only repeat myself: Here you have a continuous random variable. And it seems that it is ill-defined, since $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx\neq 1$, if I've made no mistake.

Comment: Damn, I was told i have to do this also for a discrete variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for expectation of Y:
$$E(Y)=\int_{y\in Y}yf_y(y)dy$$
However, it is easier to think of Y in terms of X:

If $0\leq X\leq.5$, $y$ will be $.5$

If $.5<X\leq1$, $y$ will be $x$.
So we can rewrite the integral as:
$$\int_0^.5.5f_y(y)dx+\int_.5^1xf_y(y)dx$$
Think of it as from $0$ to $.5$, $y$ is always $.5$, so we do not need the variable for $y$, we can just write $.5$, and from $.5$ to $1$, $y$ is always $x$, so we again do not need the variable for $y$. Now, we need to find $f_Y(y)$.

The best way to do this is to find $F_Y(y)$ in terms of x and differentiate with respect to $x$. This is very simple, since:

$F_Y(y)=x$, for all valid $y$, i.e $.5\leq y\leq1$. We differentiate to get:
$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dx}x=1$. Since it is $1$, we can just remove it from the intergral, and calculate:
$$\int_0^.5.5dx+\int_.5^1xdx=.625$$
Also, this does not make sense for a discrete variable, as $X$ is homogeneous over $[0,1]$, so it must be continuous. Maybe it was a variation where $X=1,2,...10$, $p_X(x)=.1$ and $Y=$ Max($5,X$)?